# Chef search generated node names cannot be used in recipe

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to use a chef search for certain nodes with:

```
hosts = search(:node, 'chef_environment:STG AND role:elasticsearch')
Chef::Log.warn("Hosts are #{hosts}")
hosts.each do |node|
  Chef::Log.warn("hostname is: #{node['name']} and has the following tags #{node["tags"]}")
end
```

The result of the first `Chef::Log.warn` is:

```
[2016-12-16T10:09:55+00:00] WARN: Hosts are [#<Chef::Node:0x00000002e0acc0 @chef_server_rest=nil, @name="tels01", @chef_environment="STG", @primary_runlist=#<Chef::RunList:0x00000002e0ac48 @run_list_items=[#<Chef::RunList::RunListItem:0x00000002df1568 @version=nil, @type=:role, @name="base">, #<Chef::RunList::RunListItem:0x00000002df0de8 @version=nil, @type=:role, @name="elasticsearch">]>, @override_runlist=#<Chef::RunList:0x00000002e0ab80 @run_list_items=[]>, @policy_name=nil, @policy_group=nil, @attributes=#<Chef::Node::Attribute @default={}, @env_default={}, @role_default={}, @force_default={}, @normal={"tags"=>["linux", "els"]}, @override={}, @role_override={}, @env_override={}, @force_override={}, @automatic={}, @merged_attributes=nil, @properties=nil>, @run_state={}>, ...
```

And the result of the `Chef::Log.warn("hostname is: #{node['name']} and has the following tags #{node["tags"]}")` is

```
[2016-12-16T10:09:55+00:00] WARN: hostname is:  and has the following tags ["linux", "els"]
[2016-12-16T10:09:55+00:00] WARN: hostname is:  and has the following tags ["linux", "els"]
[2016-12-16T10:09:55+00:00] WARN: hostname is:  and has the following tags ["linux", "elasticsearch"]
[2016-12-16T10:09:55+00:00] WARN: hostname is:  and has the following tags ["linux", "elasticsearch"]
[2016-12-16T10:09:55+00:00] WARN: hostname is:  and has the following tags ["linux", "elasticsearch"]
```

So I cannot get the hostname of the machines resulted from the query. I have also tried with `#{node['hostname']}` but with the same result

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Edit:

Thank you for your replies. Using `els_hosts = search(:node, 'chef_environment:STG AND role:elasticsearch')
Chef::Log.warn("Hosts are #{els_hosts}")
els_hosts.each do |host|
  Chef::Log.warn("hostname is: #{host["fqdn"]} and has the following tags #{host["tags"]}")
end` The result is the same: `Compiling Cookbooks...
[2016-12-16T12:47:18+00:00] WARN: Hosts are [#<Chef::Node:0x0000000542fbf8 @chef_server_rest=nil, @name="clj-lc-tels01", @chef_environment="LC", @primary_runlist=#<Chef::RunList:0x0000000542fb08 @run_list_items=[#<Chef::RunList::RunListItem:0x0000000542d1c8 @version=nil, @type=:role, @name="base">, #<Chef::RunList::RunListItem:0x0000000542cfe8 @version=nil, @type=:role, @name="lc_elasticsearch">]>, @override_runlist=#<Chef::RunList:0x0000000542fa18 @run_list_items=[]>, @policy_name=nil, @policy_group=nil, @attributes=#<Chef::Node::Attribute @default={}, @env_default={}, @role_default={}, @force_default={}, @normal={"tags"=>["linux", "test_els"]}, @override={}, @role_override={}, @env_override={}, @force_override={}, @automatic={}, @merged_attributes=nil, @properties=nil>, @run_state={}>, ...
[2016-12-16T12:47:18+00:00] WARN: hostname is:  and has the following tags ["linux",  "test_els"]
[2016-12-16T12:47:18+00:00] WARN: hostname is:  and has the following tags ["linux", "test_els"]
[2016-12-16T12:47:18+00:00] WARN: hostname is:  and has the following tags ["linux", "elasticsearch"]
[2016-12-16T12:47:18+00:00] WARN: hostname is:  and has the following tags ["linux", "elasticsearch"]
[2016-12-16T12:47:18+00:00] WARN: hostname is:  and has the following tags ["linux", "elasticsearch"]`

Comment: First, don't use `node` as variable. That will drive you insane, because it usually points to the very own node object.

Comment: `node` is a special name, used to refer to the actual node, you're messing your search results with the global node object. replace `|node|` by `|host|` and use that in your logs to be sure of what you're accessing.

Comment: Second, IIRC `name` should be the client name, this doesn't have to do with the hostname (but should not be empty). Consider using `host['fqdn']` or `host['hostname']`.

Comment: You can manually verify the attributes using `knife node show <node_name> -a <attribute_name>`.

Comment: @StephenKing The result of `knife node show tels01 -a hostname` is: `tels01:
  hostname:`

Comment: @StephenKing The result of `knife node show tels01 -a name` is: `tels01:
  name: tels01`

Comment: The way I do it now is saving the definition of nodes, deleting all the ohai attributes and replacing the node definition with something like `{
  "name": "tels01",
  "chef_environment": "STG",
  "normal": {
    "tags": [
      "linux",
      "test_els"
    ]
  },
  "run_list": [
    "role[base]",
    "role[elasticsearch]"
  ]
}`

Comment: That because we need to save the node definition in the chef git repo.

Comment: Feels weird to me. Chef doesn't dictate a workflow, but it reads off a bit from what I'm used to. Ignore me, if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

That should be `node.name`. The name is a real method, not an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was really coming from the fact that I used to download the nodes definitions, strip them of all ohai attributes and keep in them only the env attribute, the run list and the name. That's why I could not get the name.

Thank you all for the answers.
Gabriel